# Go client to access GAE login required apps

Tags: google-app-engine, go, oauth-2.0, google-signin

I wanted to authenticate myself (Google Account) using a golang client against protected apps on Google App Engine where `login: required` or `login: admin` is specified in app.yaml.

First I wrote a simple OAuth2 offline access client but it didn't work at all - the server just redirects clients to Google Account's sign in page.  I've tried with various Google API scopes and currently no luck.

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "io"
    "log"
    "os"

    "golang.org/x/oauth2"
    "golang.org/x/oauth2/google"
)

const (
    AppURL           = "https://login-requried-app.appspot.com"
    AuthClientID     = "....."
    AuthClientSecret = "....."
    AuthRedirectURL  = "urn:ietf:wg:oauth:2.0:oob"
    AuthScope        = "https://www.googleapis.com/auth/cloud-platform"
)

func main() {
    ctx := context.Background()
    conf := &oauth2.Config{
        ClientID:     AuthClientID,
        ClientSecret: AuthClientSecret,
        Endpoint:     google.Endpoint,
        RedirectURL:  AuthRedirectURL,
        Scopes:       []string{AuthScope},
    }

    url := conf.AuthCodeURL("state", oauth2.AccessTypeOffline)
    fmt.Printf("Visit the URL for the auth dialog: %v\n", url)
    fmt.Printf("Enter authentication code: ")

    var code string
    if _, err := fmt.Scan(&code); err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    tok, err := conf.Exchange(ctx, code)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    client := conf.Client(ctx, tok)

    res, err := client.Get(AppURL)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    defer res.Body.Close()

    log.Println(res.Status)
    io.Copy(os.Stdout, res.Body)
}
```

I'm looking for the details of GAE's user authentication modes used in such apps to write a non web browser client.  I feel it's something different than standard OAuth2 authentication/authorization after reading App Engine Users API docs and code that is receiving user information via HTTP headers like `X-AppEngine-User-Email`.

- [Users Go API Overview](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/users/)
- [google.golang.org/appengine/user package document](https://godoc.org/google.golang.org/appengine/user)
- [user.Current() implementation](https://github.com/golang/appengine/blob/master/user/user_vm.go#L15-L31) (it's for flex env but almost the same in standard env)

**UPDATE:** After some research it looks like the GAE frontend uses `SACSID` cookie for tracking authenticated sessions, which isn't related to the OAuth2 standard.  Indeed as stated in [Users Go API document](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/users/):

> Note that using OAuth to identify your users is completely orthogonal to the standard user authentication modes. For example, pages marked with login: required or login: admin will refuse to load if the user is only authenticated via OAuth.

Is there any supported way for a CLI application to acquire `SACSID` properly authorized by user's consent?

Related questions:

- [Access an App Engine app from command line using OAuth2?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/31065058/4937930)
- [On Google App Engine, can I relate a Google OAuth 2 Token and a SACSID token I got using Android's AccountManager?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8342096/4937930)

Comment: This isn't an answer but it looks to me like you want to do what the openidconnect client libraries are doing: https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OpenIDConnect#libraries. Unfortunately it doesn't appear that there is one for Go.

Answer (score 2):

Given the situation you explain here, I suggest using a [remote API](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/go/tools/remoteapi/). This way you can access App Engine services from your Go app.

First you have to configure your `app.yaml` file by adding the following:

```
- url: /_ah/remote_api
  script: _go_app
```

You also have to add the following import to your `.go` source file:

```
import _ "google.golang.org/appengine/remote_api"
```

When this is done, deploy your updated app to App Engine:

```
gcloud app deploy app.yaml
```

The website I included here includes an example on how to use the remote API. You can try it and adapt your code if this works for you.

Comment: Thanks, I've never come up with the remote API.  It could be useful for some tasks, but apparently it wouldn't suit my needs.  It provides no access to web server handlers which embody app's business logics.  I don't want to embed them into a CLI client because it requires users to keep it updated.

Comment: Have you tried using an [Identity Aware Proxy](https://cloud.google.com/iap/docs/concepts-overview) to secure your app? That way you can control the access to your app and ensure the authentication and authorization process only works for the proper users without relying on external sources.

Alternatively, you can also use [Cloud Endpoints](https://cloud.google.com/endpoints/) to have complete control over who can access your app by using JSON Web Tokens and API keys.